# Libraries / tutorials for manipulating video in java

Tags: java, video-processing

I need to do some simple video editing within a Java application, but the frameworks I've found ([JMF](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/download.html) and [FMJ](http://fmj-sf.net/index.php)) appear to be quite stale, and thus far I haven't found any evidence that either can actually edit video.  The type of operations I need are: cropping, redacting sections, and extracting clips.

I've never worked with video in any real capacity before, so I may just be misunderstanding what FMJ/JMF do, but I am still concerned by the age of the most recent releases of those tools.

What do people use to do this sort of thing? What keywords should I be using to get more relevant results?

(The specific format of video is not particularly important to me -- anything common is just fine.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may take a look on [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/index). Also some alternatives to JMF were covered in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Media_Framework#Alternatives).

Comment: Thanks! I found FMJ on that wikipedia article earlier, but somehow overlooked the xuggle link!

Answer (score 5):

[GStreamer](http://www.gstreamer.net/) has some Java bindings.