# How to split video into frames in Java

Tags: java, image, video

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Libraries / tutorials for manipulating video in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809646/libraries-tutorials-for-manipulating-video-in-java)

I'm wondering if there is any open source library that split a video into frames? I'm working on a program that takes in a video and produce a new video with some marks on the video(Face detection).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809646/libraries-tutorials-for-manipulating-video-in-java

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler.).

This [tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/xuggler-tutorial-frames-capture-video.html) may be useful.

Comment: Thanks. The tutorial is very helpful. I looked into the Xuggler, but the documentation the site is not available.

Comment: Take a look at Xuggler wiki page for a start. [link](http://wiki.xuggle.com/Main_Page)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler) it's perfect and easy

also you can use FFMPEG

Comment: Thanks. I looked into the Xuggler, but the documentation is not available in the site.

Comment: Try this http://wiki.xuggle.com/Tutorials

Comment: *"I looked into the Xuggler,"*  It pays to mention what you've looked at, and why you rejected it up front.  Please put more care into writing the question.