# Split video into small chunks

Tags: java

hello every one I want to split the large video into small chunks using Java program.Can any one have any idea about how can I achieve that. 
i am currently using this command in my java program to split video into chunks.
ffmpeg -i first.mp4 -ss 0 -t 50 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -async 1 -y 001.mp4
But to divide video into small chunks i have to write code.I want to achieve this using only one command

Comment: I guess that the video is just a sequence of bytes isn't it.

Comment: This is not really how stackoverflow works. We don't create code for you. Have you tried anything yet that we can help with?

Comment: maybe this can help? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692987/how-to-split-video-into-frames-in-java

Comment: This is a broad question. Please write code and then we might be able to help you with that.

Comment: I am currently using pHash to compare two videos.When I compare two small videos it will work fine but when I am giving large video it show me error like
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GStreamer or Xuggler can help you, i would recommend Xuggler.

here you can find some tutorials: http://goo.gl/hQdM0B