# how to write multiple video files together to create one video file

Tags: java, android, file, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I am trying to build a basic video editor in Android that will take multiple video files and simply write them one after the next back to back into one single video file, I tried creating a loop that will take all of the smaller clips and write them to one big file however this only gives me one broken file instead of writing all the files into the larger video the way that I want it to be done, how can I make this happen? below is my code which I wrote to do this, any help will go a long way thanks

```
File[] files = tempDirectory.listFiles();

    if (files != null) {

        try {

            for (File f : files) {

                FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(assembleFile);

                InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bufferLength = 0;

                while ((bufferLength = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    // add the data in the buffer to the file in the file
                    // output
                    // stream (the file on the sd card
                    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                }
                // close the output stream when done
                fileOutput.close();
                is.close();

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Glued video files become one large working video? That's news to me... Imagine that, a file format with multiple headers! Traditional video formats don't work that way.

Comment: so this cant be done?

Comment: What is a way to do this?

Comment: Video files must be read and converted into frames, then the frames must be converted back into another video. It's necessary to understand the file format to do that. I suggest you research for a video processing library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't glue the video files expecting to produce a single working video. Try using video manipulation libraries such as the ones mentioned in this question: [Libraries / tutorials for manipulating video in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809646/libraries-tutorials-for-manipulating-video-in-java)