# Java convert video into sequence

Tags: java, image, video, arraylist, bufferedimage

I couldn't find this anywhere on the internet. Is there a way to do something like:

```
ArrayList<BufferedImage> frames = VideoUtil.getFrames(getClass().getResource("video.avi"));
```

Or do I have to use an external library?

NOTE: I've searched but nowhere have I found a way to do this. The best I could find is what I want, but the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Libraries / tutorials for manipulating video in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809646/libraries-tutorials-for-manipulating-video-in-java)